# Query to return amount of orders of a specific Product ID before and after the current order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a table with two columns: `OrderId` and `ProductId`, and I need a query which will show these two columns and add another two columns, one which will tell me how many orders of this specific `ProductId` came **before** this order (`orderId`s are created in ascending order), and the other column which will tell me how many orders of this specific item came **after** this order.

So, for example, this should be the result:

| OrderId | ProductId | OrdersBefore | OrdersAfter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 245 | PR-987 | 0 | 2 |
| 246 | GH-764 | 0 | 1 |
| 247 | NV-102 | 0 | 0 |
| 248 | PR-987 | 1 | 1 |
| 249 | PR-987 | 2 | 0 |
| 250 | GH-764 | 1 | 0 |

I've been fiddling around with adding the table again as a join, tried it as a subquery, and all kinds of other possible methods but it either didn't work at all, went on endlessly or returned wrong results. So I'm basically stuck, and I'd appreciate any help or guidance.

Here are two methods I tried (others I don't remember, being that I tried so many iterations of so many methods), both never finish querying:

1.

```
SELECT OrderId
     , ProductId
     , (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Orders o2
           WHERE o2.ID < Orders.ID
               AND ProductID = ProductID
       )
       OrdersBefore
     , (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Orders o2
           WHERE o2.ID > Orders.ID
               AND ProductID = ProductID
       )
       OrdersAfter
FROM Orders
```

2. 

```
SELECT o.OrderId
     , o.ProductId
     , COUNT(DISTINCT before.ID) OrdersBefore
     , COUNT(DISTINCT after.ID) OrdersAfter
FROM Orders o
    LEFT JOIN Orders before ON before.ProductId = o.ProductId
            AND before.OrderId< o.OrderId
    LEFT JOIN Orders after ON after.ProductId = o.ProductId
            AND after.OrderId> o.OrderId
GROUP BY o.OrderId
       , o.ProductId
```

Comment: hint - [count over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  Assuming that `orderid` is how you define the ordering of the orders:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by productid order by orderid) - 1 as orders_before,
       row_number() over (partition by productid order by orderid desc) - 1 as orders_after
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a windowed `COUNT OVER`**

```sql
SELECT
  OrderId,
  ProductId,
  OrdersBefore = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ProductId ORDER BY t.OrderId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
  OrdersAfter = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ProductId ORDER BY t.OrderId ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: Sorry fixed now